# C++ Is it safe to change an exported DLL function from int to BOOL?

Tags: c++, integer, boolean, dllexport

I'm dealing with a legacy DLL that has may things that started from DOS C code back in the day where there was no concept of a boolean. But the DLL is still in active development and still evolving. Many of the older exported methods have signatures like:

```
     _declspec(dllexport) int IsConditionTrue();
```

By the appearance of the name, the function should return a `TRUE`/`FALSE` value, but since it's delcared as an `int`, the programmer has to assume the API could return anything. I'm in a round of making changes to the DLL, and am wondering if it's safe to change these declarations to use `BOOL` instead to clarify the intended API usage:

```
     _declspec(dllexport) BOOL IsConditionTrue();
```

`BOOL` is declared as `typedef int BOOL;`, so I would think that there should be no difference to the compiler or to already-compiled consumers of exported function, right? I just don't want to make the change to a dozen exported functions, then spend a week chasing down and recompiling broken executables that were consuming the exported `int` version.

Comment: if the DLL is still in active development, why not fix the DLL?

Comment: "the programmer has to assume the API could return anything" - Well depending on the sanity of the codebase, one still may have to account for it returning anything even when using `BOOL` (speaking from experience when I worked in a code base that had a few BOOLs that could end up as TRUE, FALSE, or -1).

Comment: @user4581301 - that's my plan, I'm just trying to verify that fixing the DLL to have the desired BOOl declarations instead of int won't break any existing consumers of the DLL. There are sevaral dozen applications compiled against this DLL, so changing exported signatures has the potential to break the applications that are consuming it.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish - fair enough. And in this codebase, that's never beyond possibility. But the majority of these int exports are truly boolean results, so it would be helpful of their signatures reflected that so I (or the next programmer) isn't always having to go dive the source code of the DLL to figure out what the function really returns. I'm trying to add documentation to the exported functions as I go to help with that as well (something that is completely lacking in this codebase).

Comment: @nedmech Since `BOOL` is `#define`'d as `int`, you are not actually changing anything at all. The preprocessor will simply replace all `BOOL`s with `int`s before the compiler even sees the code, so it will compile exactly the same as it was before.

Comment: Since you are doing `typedef int BOOL` changing the return type of your function to return `BOOL` instead of `int` has no effect.   A typedef is an alternative label in code for a type, not a mechanism to create a distinct type.   There would be a implications of a type mismatch if you made `BOOL` some other type - having a function return something different that the caller expects, if it still builds, gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `BOOL` is declared as `typedef int BOOL;`, so I would think that there should be no difference to the compiler or to already-compiled consumers of exported function, right?

Yes, `typedef` is just syntactic sugar and has no impact on the resulting ABI.

That said, `BOOL` does not make the code any safer for the end user, it can still return values other than `TRUE`, `FALSE` and compiler will happily accept such code. Furthermore, the user might become more "lazy" and not check these errors compared to ominous `int` which hopefully makes one actually check the documentation.

Comment: I understand that `BOOL` won't keep the function from passing values other than `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and that it's up to me as the programmer to make sure functions that I declare as `BOOL` actually comply to the contract implied by declaring them as `BOOL`. I primarily wanted to make sure I was understanding correctly that changing from `int` to `BOOL` wouldn't cause any ABI issues.